# In hibernate, wrong value used as parameter for fetching set

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

I have to hibernate entities and tables with a one to many relationship.  One is a user and the other is a car object.  I believe where the discrepancy is, is that I am attempting to join on field other than the primary key of the parent table and foreign key of the child.

For example, my tables look like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `userId` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `serial` (`serial`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



 CREATE TABLE `Car` (
      `carId` int(32) NOT NULL,
      `serial` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`carId`) USING BTREE,
      KEY `FK_USER_serial` (`serial`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_USER_serial` FOREIGN KEY (`serial`) REFERENCES `User` (`serial`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My mappings like so:

The User Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="User">
        <id name="userId" type="int">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="serial" type="string"></property>
          <set name="cars" table="Car" 
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="serial" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Car" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Car Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Car" table="Car">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="serial" type="string"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The values I have in those tables are as follows:

User:
userId=172
serial=1

Car:
carId=159
serial=1

carId=160
serial=1

I enabled trace level logging in log4j and discovered that the hibernate is trying to retrieve the cars by the "serial" field but is using the "userId" in the where clause of 172 as opposed to the 1 which would actually bring back children.

What can I change in either my table or in my mapping to have hibernate use the serial foreign key and not the userId which the Car table doesn't even have.

Comment: If you're ready to change your tables, then do the right thing and make the foreign key reference the primary key in the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JB Nizet's comment is the right solution.  I changed the primary key to serial.  It was already the unique index and is better suited to be the primary key.